# Java : Simple Variable Issue

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, libgdx

My code seems to me clean I don't understand why it won't work.

There is a button, it's supposed to change the sprite drawn when you click on it (this step works) and when you click on it it's also supposed to add +1 to my variable planetCount, the purpose of this step is to get the planet sprite drawn :

```
right.addListener(new ClickListener() {
   public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
       sound.play(0.2f);

       if (planetCount <= 4) {
           choixRegion.setRegion(choix2Region);
           choix2Region.setRegion(choix3Region);
           choix3Region.setRegion(choix4Region);
           choix4Region.setRegion(choix5Region);
           choix5Region.setRegion(choixRegion);

        } else if(planetCount < 4){
            planetCount = planetCount + 1;
        } else if(planetCount > 4){
            planetCount = 4;
        }
    }
});
```

and the problem is there, for all the planet choices it gives returns me the same screen (StartGame) to sum up if I have planetCount = 1 , it should returns me Itryon's Screen but regardless of the planetCount value it always returns StartGame screen:

```
oui.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if(planetCount == 0){
            game.setScreen(new StartGame(game));
        } else if(planetCount == 1){
            game.setScreen(new Itryon(game));
        } else if (planetCount == 2){
            game.setScreen(new Nernel(game));
        } else if(planetCount == 3){
            game.setScreen(new Abela(game));
        } else if(planetCount == 4){
            game.setScreen(new StartGame(game));
        } 
        sound.play(0.2f);
        music.stop();
        return true;
    }
```

So where is my mistake ?

Comment: The `else if` bit is only executed if the initial `if` condition is false. In your case the `else if` branch will never run.

Comment: It depends on what you want, but that would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            // ...

            if (planetCount <= 4) {
                // ...
                // when true, planetCount is not increased.
                // You can try setting planetCount = 1 at start,
                // And you'll get only Itryon's screen.
            }
            else if(planetCount < 4){
                planetCount = planetCount + 1;
            }
            else if(planetCount > 4){
                planetCount = 4;
            }
```

You can simply modify method as below:

```
     public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

           sound.play(0.2f);

           choixRegion.setRegion(choix2Region);
           choix2Region.setRegion(choix3Region);
           choix3Region.setRegion(choix4Region);
           choix4Region.setRegion(choix5Region);
           choix5Region.setRegion(choixRegion);

           // You should think about below logic.

           planetCount++;

           if (planetCount > 4) {
               planetCount = 4;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the use of the first `if else if` structure.

In your code you are never able to run the first `else if` statement, so the counter is never incremented.

You can write something like this:

```
right.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            sound.play(0.2f);

            if (planetCount < 4) {
                choixRegion.setRegion(choix2Region);
                choix2Region.setRegion(choix3Region);
                choix3Region.setRegion(choix4Region);
                choix4Region.setRegion(choix5Region);
                choix5Region.setRegion(choixRegion);
                planetCount = planetCount + 1;

            }
        }
    });
```